How to add rectangle with text like tooltip to an image with GIMP
Hi want to achieve something like this with GIMP


If you are looking for a pushbutton solution then wrong program, unless there is a script somewhere 
Otherwise, fastest is likely:

Text from text tool
On a new layer below:

Create and fill a rectangle selection with rounded corners
Complement with a stroke from a diamond brush (easily created with the brush editor)




To create the diamond:

